A strange problem with modeless dialog boxes
I'm having a problem with modeless dialog boxes. I have one in a loop that scans files in a directory, adding the files to a linked list class for later processing, using the modeless dialog box as a progress box. When I run with the debugger, F5, it works fine. When I run without the debugger, Ctrl-F5, the box stops updating after five seconds, the mouse cursor changes to an hourglass, and the "X" button in the upper right hand corner of the windows turns dim red. This condition persists until the loop is done, at which point the program continues normally.
I have consolidated the code into a minimalist example of what is going on, using only the dialog box and the loop, which simply counts to 100, with 100 millisecond delays between iterations.
Here are my Global Variables...
HWND hwndDialog1;
HDC dc;
UINT_PTR upTimer;
int wmId;
HDC hdc;

and here is the Windows Proc...
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        hwndDialog1 = CreateDialog(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), hWnd, NULL);
        break;
    
    case WM_COMMAND:
        wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
        // Parse the menu selections:
        switch (wmId)
        {
        case IDM_EXIT:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        case ID_TEST_FIRE:
            dc = GetDC(hwndDialog1);
            ShowWindow(hwndDialog1, SW_SHOW);
            TCHAR sz[5];
            for (int i = 1; i <= 100; ++i)
            {
                StringCchPrintf(sz, 5, _T("%d"), i);
                SetBkColor(dc, RGB(240, 240, 240));
                TextOut(dc, 50, 50, sz, lstrlen(sz));
                Sleep(100);
            }
            upTimer = SetTimer(hWnd, 1, 2000, NULL);
            break;
            
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
        
        break;

    case WM_TIMER:
        KillTimer(hWnd, upTimer);
        ShowWindow(hwndDialog1, SW_HIDE);
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        DestroyWindow(hwndDialog1);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

I've scoured the documentation for modeless dialog boxes, and I can't find an explanation. The strange part of this is that the code works correctly when I run with the debugger, and it freezes after five seconds when I run without the debugger. Please take a look and see if I have missed something. Thank you.

The strange part of this is that it only occurs with a Release build -- 1) That is not strange.  Programs failing in release mode is a sign of using uninitialized variables or other bugs that are covered up in debug mode.  2) Stop using new[] and delete[] and instead use std::vector<TCHAR>.  3) Use std::list instead of your home made linked list class.  4) Just because the function you posted is where the crash occurs, it doesn't mean the origins of why the crash occurred is in this function.

You don't need to new[] your buffers (and sizeof() won't work for such buffers anyway). Just declare your buffers statically, eg: TCHAR szOpenFileName[MAX_PATH]; But in any case, why are you using GetOpenFileName() to select a folder? That dialog only works with files, not with folders. For what you are trying to do, use SHBrowseForFolder() instead, or IFileOpenDialog with the FOS_PICKFOLDERS flag. Either way, you are best off not messing around with (Get|Set)CurrentDirectory() at all.  Use absolute paths with FindFirstFile() instead of relative paths.

Is this the Desktop Window Manager deciding that your window isn’t responding to messages quickly enough and just ghosts the window? The fact you get your results after the same amount of time suggests it’s still working. I notice you are calculating a SHA1 in your loop - any large files that would make that take a long time?

I don't know anything about the "Desktop Window Manager", so I can't answer that question. I just know that I am calling TextOut() repeatedly in the loop. I thought it might be a timing issue, as a Release executable would run faster, so I added a 5ms delay in the loop - no help.

@AlexSokolek at first you need move code to scan folder/process files to another thread and post messages from this thread to UI thread. this is main point. use FindFirstFile is worst choice - use FindFirstFileEx or NtQueryDirectoryFile . +some questions of implementation, etc. but again - first and main - you need here working thread

Also, I noted that if I press ESC before the freeze, it stops properly, but if I press ESC after the freeze it does not respond. Its almost as if a part of the loop is being chopped off. Lastly, I noted that a Debug build also fails if I start with F5 (Run without debugger).

And, yes, I do a SHA1 for each file in the directory. That does take a long time. (45 seconds for the entire directory.) That's why I added the progress dialog box, so the user could know it still working.

RbMm: I thought about using a worker thread, but that seems like more work (LOL) than its worth. Anyway, even if I do the work in another thread, the main thread will still be stalled waiting for the results.

Remy: I used GetOpenFileName() because I did not know how to use SHBrowseForFolder() or IFileOpenDialog(). That's why I have the user pick a file and then I rip the file off of the returned value. Another reason for using what I did was that would give the user the option of seeing the files in the folder, so he could know he has the right folder to scan.

(Parts 1 and 2) An update, after several hours of testing...
1.) It does not matter if it is a Release build or a Debug build. (I was in error.) What matters is how the app is launched. If I launch with F5 (Run without debugger) the odd behavior is manifest. If I Launch with F5 (Run with debugger) the odd behavior does not manifest. Both Release and Debug builds exhibit the same behavior.
2.) I commented out all of the code except the dialog box code itself and the problem still persists. This makes me think the problem is with the dialog box code itself.

Part 3
3.) I have noted a second symptom... When the loop is done, I start a three second timer. I don't hide the dialog box until the timer expires. This gives the user a chance to see the results after the dialog box stops moving. When I run without debugging, the dialog box blanks out at the end of the loop and then disappears after three seconds. It does not matter if the dialog box "freezes up" while counting up. I tried this with a second directory with fewer files... This way the "freezing" does not occur, but the blanking out does. (That is, without the debugger.)

Part 4
I'm pretty sure this has something to do with how I create, show, and/or paint the dialog box. Note that I am not using a dialog box procedure. It is supposed to be optional. I paint in the dialog box with a DC obtained from GetDC(). Supposedly, the dialog box manager handles all of the dialogbox messages, similar to DefWindowsProc().
Please take another look at the code, concentrating on the dialog box code. I remain at a loss to explain this. Thank you.

p.s. Here is the creation code...  (Sorry, I could not bracket the code.) case WM_CREATE:
// Create the modeless dialog box - We will display it later in the process procedure
hWndProgressBox = CreateDialog(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_PROGRESS_BOX), hWnd, NULL);
if (hWndProgressBox == NULL)
{
MessageBeep(MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
MessageBox(hWnd, _T("CreateDialog returned NULL"),
_T("Warning!"), MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
}
break;

p.s. Ignore the previous comment. I was able to add the creation code to the original question. Again, thank you.

I noted something else... When the dialog box freezes, the mouse cursor changes from an arrrow to an hourglass and the "X" button in the upper right corner of the parent window changes to dim red. Interesting, eh...

Yet another observation... It takes five seconds for the dialog box to freeze and the cursor and "X" button to change. It does not matter how many files are in the directory to scan, or how much delay I add to each iteration of the loop - its always five seconds.
I'm thinking that Windows is timing out waiting for something to happen, but it never happens. I tried creating a dummy dialog box procedure which returns false. That did not help. (Returning true, however, results in a dead application that has to be terminated with Task Manager.)

@AlexSokolek "It does not matter if it is a Release build or a Debug build" -- Why does the question still claim otherwise? Comments are not for updates to the question. The [edit] link is for updates to the question. Pretend that the comments could disappear tomorrow and someone comes to read your question for the first time. Edit your question so that it is accurate and understandable to that person. (Don't try to preserve the history -- there's a link for that as well.)

"I ahve no idea where I'm going wrong, so I thought it best to post the whole routine." -- Having enough code to reproduce the problem is good, but minimizing the code is also good. For example, what happens if you remove the lines that save and restore the current directory? (There are no "other routines" in a [mre].) Same issue? Then drop those lines from your example code. See what else you can drop. Show us the problem, not your program.

@AlexSokolek - at first this is not "more work". this is only correct solution. and " main thread will still be stalled waiting for the results." - absolute false. UI thread must not wait for results. it must simply rrun message loop

Repost, providing the latest knowledge and a minimalist example of the code.

Questions are for questions, not answers. The question should remain as a question so it can be found by future people with the same issue. (Normally, the next bit of advice would be to answer your own question, but you have already done that. The existence of your answer is sufficient to indicate that this question has an answer. Accepting it after the required wait will indicate that you consider this solved.)

Found a reference on Meta for "Questions are for questions, not answers": What is the appropriate action when the answer to a question is added to the question itself? I thought there was something in the help center about this, but I couldn't find it today.

I have solved the problem! In the original version of the program, I was calling PeekMessage() in the long loop, filtering for WM_KEYDOWN with PM_REMOVE and checking for VK_ESCAPE. I received feedback that said I was stalling the message loop, so I changed the PeekMessage() call to not filter at all, and then to check for WM_KEYDOWN and VK_ESCAPE. Problem solved. The code no longer freezes, in debug mode or in non-debug mode.
// Check for ESC pressed - Abort if so.
MSG msg;
if (!PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) continue;
if (msg.message != WM_KEYDOWN || msg.wParam != VK_ESCAPE) continue;
pCHashedFiles->Reset();
bEscapePressed = true;
break;


"In the original version of the program, I was calling PeekMessage() in the long loop" -- In the current version of the question, there is no call to PeekMessage(), which means the question lacks a [mre] and the question is useless to future visitors with the same issue. (The goal of this site is to create "a library of detailed, high-quality answers to every question about programming". It's just a desirable side-effect that the person asking the question gets a useful answer.)
